# Plotting/Exporting the Spatial Random Effects in BYM model - CARBayes - in R

Tags: r, export, random, modelling

I am working with visceral leishmaniasis disease cases in a small city with 100 polygons (census tract).

I have run a Bayesian Spatial Modeling - Conditional Autoregressive model (CAR) Poisson (BYM model, CARBayes package) in R.

I would like to know how to plot/export the Spatial Random Effects of my model on a map?

**Details:**

```
library(rgdal)
library(CARBayes)
```

**1. Open shapefile**

```
VL <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "VL")  
spat.data = readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "VL")
spat.data2 <- spTransform(spat.data, CRS("+proj=longlat+datum=WGS84 +no_defs")) 
names(spat.data2) 
spplot(spat.data2)
```

**2. Matrix**

```
W=poly2nb(spat.data2)
W2 <- nb2mat(W, style="B")
```

**3. Equation (number of cases disease is explained by altitude)**

```
eq1 = LV~offset(log(DOGS))+altitude
```

**4. BYM model**

```
modelbym <- S.CARbym(formula=eq1, data=spat.data2, family="poisson", W=W2, burnin=100000, n.sample=300000, thin=20)
print(modelbym)
```

Answer (score 1):

I always forget which of the greek letters in CARBayes refers to what, but can usually work it out from the dimensions of the things returned in the `samples`. Using the toy example from `?S.CARbym`, I see:

```
> str(model$samples)
List of 6
 $ beta  : mcmc [1:30, 1:3] 0.254 0.262 0.279 0.27 0.279 ...
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1 30 1
 $ psi   : mcmc [1:30, 1:100] -0.481 -0.468 -0.603 -0.625 -0.557 ...
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1 30 1
 $ tau2  : mcmc [1:30, 1] 0.0321 0.0376 0.0388 0.0379 0.0369 ...
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1 30 1
 $ sigma2: mcmc [1:30, 1] 0.0423 0.0482 0.0531 0.0543 0.0571 ...
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1 30 1
 $ fitted: mcmc [1:30, 1:100] 32.8 33 31.5 31.3 32 ...
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1 30 1
 $ Y     :Class 'mcmc'  atomic [1:1] NA
  .. ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1 1 1
```

This example has 100 data points and 30 MCMC samples (it runs very quickly and is only meant to check things actually run, results are probably meaningless).

The `psi` component has 100 columns and 30 rows. That looks promising. One row for each MCMC sample, 1 column for each spatial location. That usually convinces me, but let's also check the vignette with `vignette("CARBayes")` (slightly mashed by being pasted from a PDF):

`Binomial - Y k ∼ Binomial(n k , θ k ) and ln(θ k /(1 − θ k )) = x ⊤
k β + O k + ψ k`

That's a Poisson GLM with the usual beta.X covariates, offsets Ok and spatial effect psi_k.

To show the posterior distribution for any spatial location, use the corresponding column of the `models$samples$psi` matrix.

For example, the 100 posterior means are:

```
> pmean = apply(model$samples$psi,2,mean)
> length(pmean)
[1] 100
```

and you can map those because they are in the same order as the data.

Any other statistics for your areal units you want you can derive from columns of that matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It is not available the spatial random effects, but the sum of spatial and non-spatial random effects is. It can be obtained for:

`pmean = apply(model$samples$psi,2,mean)`

and exported as ".CSV" file using rgdal package.

`write.csv(pmean, file = "pmean.csv")`

Then I could manipulate this data in ArcGIS.